# Quick calculation of a symmetric product with two indices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, symmetric-functions, symmetric-polynomials

Say I have a product $\prod_{1\le i \le N-1}\prod_{i<j\le N-1} (1+t_i t_j a_{ij})$, where $a_{ij}$s are real number. I want to calculate the coefficient of $\prod_{0 \le i < N} t_i$. Is there an efficient way of doing it? We may assume $N$ to be even.

The coefficient is clearly: $\sum_{\{ i_0,\cdots,i_n \} \in Aut(Z^N)} a_{i_0 i_1} \cdots a_{i_{N-2} i_{N-1}}$. The question is how to calculate such symmetric products efficiently.

A similar question for the coefficient of $t^m,m \le N-1$ in the product $\prod_{1\le i \le N-1} (1+t a_{i})$ is settled by re-expressing the symmetric polynomials as a linear combination of power sums using classic Girard–Newton formulae.

I am in essence asking for a generalization of Girard-Newton formula for two indices.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with $\operatorname{Aut}(Z^N)$, but it looks to me that what you are after is the hafnian of the matrix $(a_{ij})$. Is your question how to compute the hafnian efficiently?

Comment: As for your second example, the coefficient of $\prod_{1\leq i<N/2} t_i$ in $\prod_{1\leq i<N-1}(1+t_ia_i)$ is simply $\prod_{1\leq i<N/2} a_i$. No need for Girard-Newton formulas. Maybe I misunderstand your question completely.

Comment: @HjalmarRosengren Thanks for pointing out the error. I have update the question.

Comment: @HjalmarRosengren Yes! I will close the problem.